# Jquery.load displaces dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Jquery load in dialog box.

I spent all night trying to figure out why the dialog box shifts to the right side of the screen when I loaded another file. Apparently loading different pages can affect it randomly. It can be center but at the very bottom, but I don't know why it is happening. All I know is the loading another page into a dialog box displaces the dialog box from the center.

This is the code i have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="ProfilePage/jqueries.js"></script>           

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(
            function()
            {
               $("#box").load("jquery1.html").dialog({modal:true,height:400,width:400});          
            }            
        )         
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="parent" style="background-color:red;height:800px;width:800px;">
        <div id="circle" style="position:relative;left:0px;height:800px;width:400px;background-color:green;float:left;">
        </div>
       <div id="box">
            I want milk
        </div>
        <div id="sds" style="position:relative;float:left;left:5px;height:800px;width:399px;background-color:yellow;">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the load and just put a normal text in the div it works fine. 
Can someone suggest an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just try to add it to the new line

```
 $("#box").load("jquery1.html")
 $("#box").dialog({modal:true,height:400,width:400});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..but it didn't work. It still shifts the dialog box to right corner of the screen.
Calling load moves the contents on the original file..the divs are relative..